# How to get properly userId from strapi when login?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, strapi

I am migrating from strapi 3.6.8 (mongodb-mongo cluster) to 4.2 (mysql -azuremysql) with React native Expo CLI, I am testing this new version locally but I have this error when i login and try to get auth data from user i dont receive `idUser` only `token`. The interesting part is when I refresh the app (not clossing session) and go to `Account Screen` I can finally get `idUser` if I close session and login with another user, have same problem.

This is where i try to get `idUser` (`Account Screen`)

```
import useAuth from "../../Hooks/useAuth";
export default function Account() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  console.log(auth);
  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      (async () => {
        const response = await getMeApi(auth.token);
        setUser(response);
      })();
    }, [])
  );
```

This is `useAuth` (just a bridge between `AuthContext` and other components)

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../Context/AuthContext";

export default () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

This is `AuthContext`

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({
  auth: undefined,
  login: () => null,
  logout: () => null,
});

export default AuthContext;
```

This is what i have printing `auth`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setUser(response);` call takes in a response from the Strapi User Permissions provider which looks something like this:

```
data : {
  user: {
    ...
  },
  jwt: ...
}
```

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#login.

Trying to access idUser on this object is not defined.